# Android SDK can't detect Java JDK

Tags: android, sdk

Whenever I run the install for Android SDK it comes up saying "Detect wether Java SE Development Kit is installed"

it lets me go back, click next or cancel but every time I click them it does absolutely nothing.

I've looked on Google and found on this site some guy had the same problem but it wasn't clear how he solved it.

When I do version -java in CMD nothing returns

edit: i noticed the java logo flashes at the bottom where my opened programs are

edit2: believe it or not, I had to spam the next button just as i went onto the next screen, it is now installed.

Comment: Are your ENVIROMENT VARIABLES set up correctly to point to your jdk?

Comment: it's set to > C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

Comment: Try C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin
Also make sure it's at the beginning of your path, otherwise it may try to use your installed JRE and the the JDK

Comment: Check this link >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588548/help-jdk-not-detected-problem-during-android-sdk-tools-setup

Problem is solved in that question...